# jQuery button not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, clone

I'm trying to clone a table row. This is not working. Even `console.log();` is not working.

I'm trying to clone the 'table-wrapper' div.

**The HTML**

```
 <div class="table-wrapper">

  <tr>

      <td style="width: 300px">
        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        @foreach($products as $product)
          <option value="{{$product->id}}">{{$product->product_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
      </td>

      <td style="width: 100px;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
      </td>

      <td style="width: 300px">
        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
          <option>Dag</option>
          <option>Week</option>
          <option>Weekend</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
          <option>0</option>
          <option>6</option>
          <option>21</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td style="width: 150px;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
      </td>

      <td style="padding-top: 20px;">
        <p>&euro;</p>
      </td>


  </tr>
```

**The JS file**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );

    $('#newcollection').click(function () {
      $(".table-wrapper:first").clone().insertAfter(".table-wrapper:last");
    });

    $('#newinput').click(function () {
      $(".rent-wrapper:first").clone().insertAfter(".rent-wrapper:last");
    });


});
```

**The button**

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <input type="button" id="newcollection" class="btn btn-primary" value="+">
  </div>
</div>
```

Do you know why this isn't working? As i said even console.log(); is not working.

EDIT: The JS file is included. It logs: 'ready' on page load and the other button does work.

-----------------------------[EDIT]--------------------------------------------

I've created a new table by using bootstrap's table example. Even with this new table it doesn't work. When i click the button it doesn't trigger anything. Even in the console it doesn't log anything. (except for 'ready!')

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<input type="button" id="newcollection" class="btn btn-primary" value="+">
</div>
```

**The included JS files**

```
<script src="{!! env('APP_URL') !!}/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="{!! env('APP_URL') !!}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="{!! env('APP_URL') !!}/js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script src="{!! env('APP_URL') !!}/js/pace.min.js"></script>
<script src="{!! env('APP_URL') !!}/js/retina.min.js"></script>
<script src="{!! env('APP_URL') !!}/js/jquery.cookies.js"></script>
<script src="{!! env('APP_URL') !!}/js/main.js"></script> // This is the file i'm currently editting.

<script src="{!! env('APP_URL') !!}/js/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<script src="{!! env('APP_URL') !!}/js/morris.min.js"></script>
<script src="{!! env('APP_URL') !!}/js/raphael-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="{!! env('APP_URL') !!}/js/bootstrap-wizard.min.js"></script>
<script src="{!! env('APP_URL') !!}/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<script src="{!! env('APP_URL') !!}/js/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: This might be a stupid question but are you including your JS file in your HTML?

Comment: Not a stupid question. I've forgot to say that i've included my JS file in my html file. It's working because it does log 'ready' when a page has been loaded. Also, the other clone button does work.

Comment: Is the button created/loaded dynamically at some time after the page loads (e.g. due to an event or ajax call), by any chance?

Comment: To be honest i have no idea. This is the only JS file i have.

Comment: So the button markup is static in the page's original HTML, and not created by some other means?

Comment: The button is static. Hardcoded in the HTML file.

Comment: `$(".row-collection:first").clone()` ... Well, there's no `row-collection` class anywhere in the HTML.  So this won't match anything.

Comment: I've edditted it. It's because i've changed class names because things arent working. I've edditted my post but it's still not working.

Comment: @itvba: Define "not working".  Because once you edited the jQuery selector, it works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/3ncfjx0u/

Comment: just noticed, there could be problems because your markup is invalid and doesn't contain a `<table>` tag round the rows. David's example _does_, and is valid HTML. That could be the difference.

Comment: Though even when I update to remove the `<table>` tags (still invalid, but worth testing), it still "works".

Comment: Interesting. There's obviously something wrong with how itvba's page is constructed then, something we can't see from an abstract set of snippets. Because clearly the code works, as you've found, even with the dodgy markup.

Comment: I doubt this fixes your problem, but your button HTML has an extra closing `</div>`

Comment: I've updated my post. It still doesn't work. Can you guys check my edit? I've created a new table because the structure of the other table was a bit messy.

Comment: @itvba: The code still works *exactly* as I'd expect it to: https://jsfiddle.net/3ncfjx0u/1/  Unless you can actually demonstrate or even describe the problem, there's nothing here for us to solve.  "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything.  Because the code is demonstrably doing exactly what we would expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

you made mistake here

> $(".table-wrapper:first")

you just want to repeat the `tr` but you are targeting `.table-wrapper` class element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");

  $('#newcollection').click(function() {
    $(".table-wrapper tr").eq(0).clone().insertAfter(".table-wrapper tr:last");
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>

      <td style="width: 300px">

      </td>

      <td style="width: 100px;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
      </td>

      <td style="width: 300px">
        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
          <option>Dag</option>
          <option>Week</option>
          <option>Weekend</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
          <option>0</option>
          <option>6</option>
          <option>21</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td style="width: 150px;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
      </td>

      <td style="padding-top: 20px;">
        <p>&euro;</p>
      </td>


    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <input type="button" id="newcollection" class="btn btn-primary" value="+">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What was the problem?  What did you change?  How does your change correct the problem?  Just dumping code doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @David I edited my answer, that will help for all your question

Comment: I've updated my post. It still doesn't work. Can you guys check my edit? I've created a new table because the structure of the other table was a bit messy.

Comment: @itvba, update my previous code by this code.  `$('#newcollection').click(function() {
    $(".table-striped tbody tr").eq(0).clone().insertAfter(".table-striped tbody tr:last");
  });`

Comment: or `$('#newcollection').click(function() { $(".table-striped tbody").append($(".table-striped tbody tr").eq(0).clone()); });` both code will work